# aws: accessing public network over nat gateway without giving full access to inbound connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc

I'm configuring an infrastructure with

- 1 VPC
- 2 subnets (1 private (A) (10.0.1.0/24) + 1 private (B) (10.0.2.0/24) + 1 public (10.0.99.0/24))

Both subnets are sub projects and I need to isolate access between subnets.

Because subnets need to access to internet, I've created a NAT gateway, which is located under public subnet.

NACL for subnet A -  10.0.1.0/24 below;

```
* inbound
ALLOW:  10.0.99.0/24
DENY: ALL
* outbound:
ALLOW: ALL
```

With this current configuration private network instances don't connect to public network, when I change inbound rule to ALLOW:ALL (or ALLOW: 8.8.8.8 for example), they do. (yes, inbound)

So the question is, how can I allow all outgoing connections without allowing all incoming connections.

ps. there are around 10 subnets, so I cannot specify incoming connections from other subnets to block, I would like to block everything but exceptions.

Comment: Added Entry in Route tables ?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do things the hard way.  You really should not need network ACLs **at all**... everything you need should be easily accomplished by security groups.  If the traffic isn't allowed by a security group, it's denied.  Security groups are stateful, handling the return path for TCP and UDP sessions automatically.

Comment: It's completely wrong approach to security implementation.  If you design your network to give a chance to instances allow connection from everywhere, one day you'll forget to implement blocking rule at one of your new machines. You should isolate projects on networking level, not at instance level. Managing networking isolation in security groups looks like putting all servers to same group and isolate using iptables.

Answer (score 2):

Allow ephemeral ports to do return traffic (ie on 1024-65536) from outside and allow outgoing from private on service ports (ie 80,443)

NACL are not a stateful firewall so you must do something like this to get it to work.  If you are running services on higher ports that *might* be in the ephemeral range then it's probably simplest to block these with security group rules

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_NACLs.html scenario 2

Comment: As I don't want to give access between subnets, it doesn't work for me. For example with this configuration, instances under subnet B can connect to private subnet B mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, basically after allowing internal connections from current subnet and vpn public subnet, putting a deny rule for all vpc and put allow for ephemeral ports afterwards.

Here is an example;

Explanation first

```
VPC:  10.0.0.0/16
project1-subnet-A: 10.0.2.0/24
project1-subnet-B: 10.0.3.0/24
project2-subnet-A: 10.0.4.0/24
project2-subnet-B: 10.0.5.0/24
management-subnet-A: 10.0.98.0/24
```

[image]

[NACL for project1-subnet-A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2qzL.png)

And explanation for rules;

```
 10 - allow all traffic inside subnet (not required)
 11 - allow all traffic from project1-B-subnet (same project, second availability zone)
 50 - allow all traffic from management subnet A (vpn)
 51 - allow all traffic from management subnet B(vpn)
 100- deny all traffic from VPC (except above networks)
 200- accept return traffic
 201-accept ICMP packages for connectivity test (not required)
 500-service related
```